# NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : Conversion from swift 3 to swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion

Hello I am currently adding some NSformatting to my textView following a tutorial, but I'm kind of stuck on a code of line I think the code was written on swift 3, I am on swift 4.2, here is the line of code on swift 3 :

```
attributedText.addAttributes(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
```

The most coherent way I found was:

```
 attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.value(forKey: paragraphStyle)], range: NSRange(location: 0
            , length: length))
```

But still I get the error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more content

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `addAttributes:value:range` (plural) doesn't exist not even in Swift 3

`NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` has been changed to `NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle`

```
attributedText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked , I've must missed the typo , that works flawlessly, thank you